# VB.NET how to throw a command from a server to client?

Tags: vb.net, client-server

Please, give me a head start :/ i really don't know where to start from here.
I am now a frequent user of VB.NET 2010 and now I encountered another hurdle,
my first project (Electronic Smart Card Attendance System) was successful but
now i want to experiment more on server-client vb programming.

How do I throw a VB.NET command from a server form
to client form remotely..? for example:

When I click "show button click event" on the form from server computer,
it will show the form / results that I wanted to show on the client's computer / VB.NET GUI.

I just want to know the syntax/code blocks that I may use.

I'm sorry if I sound a bit bossy but it's kinda frustrating X(

Help will be greatly appreciated <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these out:

[[VB.Net] Multi-Client Server Async Socket Example](http://tech.reboot.pro/showthread.php?tid=86)

[[Tutorial][VB.Net] Asynchronized Server/Client Demo(using sockets)](http://www.supportforums.net/showthread.php?tid=18870)

Comment: Thank you for the links sir! This will help definitely help me start on my multi-client quiz system project. Much respect. :)